# Flutter: Taking screenshoot of clipped widget using RepaintBoundary

Tags: flutter, dart, crop

I want to create an image cropper with Flutter, I tried using ClipPath to make the cropper, and RepaintBoundary to take snapshot for the visible area. **The problem** that RepaintBoundary is taking screenshot of the entire child widget, and not for the clipped area only.

Code:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

typedef cropValue = Future<Uint8List> Function();

class CropController {
  cropValue crop;
  void dispose() {
    crop = null;
  }
}

class CropInteractiveView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool allowRotationGesture;
  final double cropPixelRatio;
  final CropController cropController;

  const CropInteractiveView(
      {Key key,
      @required this.child,
      this.cropController,
      this.allowRotationGesture = false,
      this.cropPixelRatio = 3.0})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CropInteractiveViewState createState() => _CropInteractiveViewState();
}

class _CropInteractiveViewState extends State<CropInteractiveView> {
  final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
  static GlobalKey repaintKey = GlobalKey();

  Future<Uint8List> crop() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary repaintBoundary =
        repaintKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image =
        await repaintBoundary.toImage(pixelRatio: widget.cropPixelRatio);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    return pngBytes;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    CropController _controller = widget.cropController;
    if (_controller != null) {
      _controller.crop = crop;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.loose,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Center(
            child: RepaintBoundary(
              key: repaintKey,
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: CropClipper(),
                child: MatrixGestureDetector(
                    shouldRotate: widget.allowRotationGesture,
                    onMatrixUpdate: (matrix, translationDeltaMatrix,
                        scaleDeltaMatrix, rotationDeltaMatrix) {
                      setState(() {
                        notifier.value = matrix;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Transform(
                        transform: notifier.value,
                        child: Container(
                            color: Colors.amberAccent, child: widget.child))),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CropClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      // ..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
      ..addRect(Rect.fromCenter(
          center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
          width: 200.0,
          height: 300.0))
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Screenshots:

[App Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmNsv.jpg)

[Crop Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GtKH.jpg) The desired result shouldn't be surrounded with white area.

Is there a walkaround for such situation?

Comment: have you found a solution?